# is there a way to use keyPressed in KeyListener like the mouseClicked in the MouseListener in Java?

Tags: java, keylistener

the KeyListener is working fine but I can't figure out how make it execute a line of code only once, similar to mouseClicked in the MouseListener class. (when I press a key it will execute code in a loop until the key is released, I only want it to execute once every time it's pressed)

edit: this is for a pause feature in a game

Code:

```
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    toggleKey(e.getKeyCode(), true);

    }


    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
        //toggleKey(e.getKeyCode(), true);
    } else {
        toggleKey(e.getKeyCode(), false);
    }


    }
    public boolean paused = false;
    public void toggleKey(int keyCode, boolean isPressed) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_W || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP)      {up.toggle(isPressed);}
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_S || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {down.toggle(isPressed);}
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_A || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {left.toggle(isPressed);}
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_D || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {right.toggle(isPressed);}
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
        pause.toggle(isPressed);
    }
}
```

class trying to use it:

```
    if (input.pause.isPressed()) {
     input.paused = true;
    if (input.paused & input.pause.isPressed()) {
    paused = false;
    }
    }
    if (!input.paused) {
    frames++;
    render();
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried that isn't working.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: You should be using the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to do this is to detect whether it is the first time it is run.`

```
boolean b = false;

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
     if(!b){
          //do stuff
     }
     b = true;
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
     b = false;
}
```

The issue with this code is that you cannot hold down multiple keys at once, The way to fix this is to use a different boolean for each key you want to use.

Comment: huh, that simple... Thanks!

Comment: If you want to do this for many keys you should put the booleans in an array. Also If you have a loop you can use the booleans to have better key detection.

Comment: You can also mark a answer as correct or upvote it.